# Core Graphics- Using CGGradient with strokes and text

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, gradient

So here is my code for creating a particular gradient:

```
     let newBlueOne = UIColor(red: 0.141, green: 0.776, blue: 0.863,     alpha: 1.000)
    let newBlueTwo = UIColor(red: 0.318, green: 0.290, blue: 0.616, alpha: 1.000)
```

And here is the code for the gradient itself:

```
let newBlue = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [newBlue1.CGColor, newBlue2.CGColor], [0, 1])!
```

Here is the code for the rectangle I'm trying to make:

```
      let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 22, y: 35, width: 194, height: 38), cornerRadius: 19)
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    rectanglePath.addClip()
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, translucent1, CGPoint(x: 119, y: 35), CGPoint(x: 119, y: 73), CGGradientDrawingOptions())
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1
    rectanglePath.stroke()
```

I want to use that newBlue gradient above as the stroke colour for this rectangle created. I also want to change the colour of some text to that newBlue gradient. Unfortunately, I can't quite figure it out. Can anyone help?

I appreciate your responses and look forward to reading them. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly stroke a path with a gradient.

To do what you want, you will need to go to the Core Graphics Layer, and use the CGContext Functions.

First, you create your path, and set its various properties, such as line weight.

Then, you use the CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context) function.  Look it up in the CGContext documentation.

Then, you use the resultant path as a clip path.

And then, you paint that area with your gradient.

Like This:

```
override  func  drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let newBlueOne = UIColor(red: 0.141, green: 0.776, blue: 0.863, alpha: 1.000)
    let newBlueTwo = UIColor(red: 0.318, green: 0.290, blue: 0.616, alpha: 1.000)
    let newBlue = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [newBlueOne.CGColor, newBlueTwo.CGColor], [0, 1])!

    let  lineWeight: CGFloat = 20.0

    let  context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    let  rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 200.0, 200.0)
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWeight)
    CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath(context)
    CGContextClip(context)

    let  startPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect))
    let  endPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect))
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, newBlue, startPoint, endPoint, CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0))
}
```

I only addressed painting the border.  I don't know about the text.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand how to do it. I just want to add a gradient to the stroke of the element and add a gradient to the text as well

Comment: "I just want to add a gradient": You can't “just” add a gradient. The way you draw a gradient is fundamentally **different** from the way you stroke a path. This answer explains what to do. You can read [“Using a CGGradient Object” in the *Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-SW4) for more information.